# How to obtain background color of the on screen windows in Mac

Tags: macos, colors, background, window, screen

I am developing an Mac-Desktop application in which I want to obtain background color of all the on-screen windows.

The function 'CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo' returns array of all on-screen windows with its size, alpha value etc.

Is there any method to obtain background color of all the on-screen windows?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. See the [Quartz Window Service Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) where `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` is listed.

In any case, there is no concept of a "window background color" in OS X. There's no configurable background color which is then automatically put behind various objects on a window.

Instead, use `CGWindowListCreateImage` to create an image of the window, and get the color somehow representative of that window, according to your own criterion.